# Exception throws when AM configured with BAM (MySql) access the statistics page in the publisher

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-bam

I have found this [link](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-1588) which explains my issue perfectly. In short :

> Exception throws when AM configured with BAM (MySql) access the statistics page in the publisher

My problem is exactly this issue.

Is there a solution for the version 1.6.0 ?

Comment: Have you made invocations to any of the exposed services in the API Manager so that stats would be generated.

Comment: No,. 
I tried to see the stats after configure AM + BAM + Mysql to verify that the installation was correct and I have encountered this error.

Comment: Please make an invocation and check. Tables in DB is created only after a invocation is made.

Comment: Sorry. When you say "make an invocation". What is exactly?

Comment: call the API which will create and populate the DB

Answer (score 0):

Try to drop all the virtual tables in hive using a hive script.

In this case **drop table APIRequestSummaryData**

https://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Adding+and+Editing+Analytic+Scripts

Comment: I have tried before and i have opened this other error question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537498/wso2-bam-hive-error