# WSO2 BAM Hive NoSuchObjectException Error

Tags: hive, wso2, wso2-bam

I have configured BAM 2.4.0 as indicated in the document 
[Monitoring using WSO2 BAM](https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM150/Monitoring+using+WSO2+BAM).
I am using MySQL.

When I try to run the script for drop table as explained on section "Changing the statistics database" from BAM Management Console, I've received this error.
Any idea?

```
[2014-05-08 11:01:19,948] ERROR {hive.ql.metadata.Hive} -  NoSuchObjectException(message:default.APIFaultSummaryData table not found)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler$17.run(HiveMetaStore.java:1222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler$17.run(HiveMetaStore.java:1217)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.executeWithRetry(HiveMetaStore.java:360)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.get_table(HiveMetaStore.java:1217)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:734)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:901)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:843)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.dropTable(DDLTask.java:3127)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:250)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:129)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1351)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:934)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServer$HiveServerHandler.execute(HiveServer.java:201)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:187)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.executeHiveQuery(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:569)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:282)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:189)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

---

**UPDATE ERROR**

```
[2014-05-08 13:58:00,004]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask} -  Running script executor task for script am_stats_analyzer_503. [Thu May 08 13:58:00 CEST 2014]
Hive history file=/u01/app/wso2bam-2.4.0/tmp/hive/wso2-querylogs/hive_job_log_root_201405081356_596525563.txt
OK
OK
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
[main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf  - Using hive-site.xml found on CLASSPATH at /u01/app/wso2bam-2.4.0/repository/conf/advanced/hive-site.xml
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.StAXDialectDetector).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Execution log at: /u01/app/wso2bam-2.4.0/repository/logs//wso2carbon.log
[2014-05-08 13:58:02,423]  WARN {org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient} -  Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
[2014-05-08 13:58:03,779] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.bam.notification.task.NotificationDispatchTask} -  Error executing notification dispatch task: Cannot borrow client for TCP,1.33.33.127:7612,TCP,1.33.33.127:7712
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.exception.AgentException: Cannot borrow client for TCP,1.33.33.127:7612,TCP,1.33.33.127:7712
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.authenticator.AgentAuthenticator.connect(AgentAuthenticator.java:58)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.DataPublisher.start(DataPublisher.java:273)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.DataPublisher.<init>(DataPublisher.java:211)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bam.notification.task.NotificationDispatchTask.initPublisherKS(NotificationDispatchTask.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bam.notification.task.NotificationDispatchTask.execute(NotificationDispatchTask.java:188)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:67)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to 1.33.33.127 on port 7712
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:212)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:166)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.pool.client.secure.SecureClientPoolFactory.makeObject(SecureClientPoolFactory.java:90)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.pool.client.secure.SecureClientPoolFactory.makeObject(SecureClientPoolFactory.java:48)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.authenticator.AgentAuthenticator.connect(AgentAuthenticator.java:50)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:407)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:208)
        ... 16 more
```

---

**IMAGE UPLOADED**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your first time configuring BAM with API manager, then you may not have run hive query earlier, so no tables to drop. So please continue with your testing and see whether rest of the things testing, there is no issue with error unless no such tables.

Comment: i have seen that in database the tables (API_xxxx) not exists.
I have configured AM with BAM Statistics to false.
When i have restarted AM the tables are been created on Mysql.
But only are five tables and they not are the same of the script indicate on document (drop table APIRequestData;
drop table APIRequestSummaryData;
drop table APIVersionUsageSummaryData;,....).

Comment: well if you don't have install  AM stat tool box then you don't see "am_stats_analyzer_XX"  script in script in Analytics--List scripts,  so then you don't get these tables

Comment: The script was installed.
But when i have started BAM, i see this error many times.

I put the error on update Question

Comment: Try whether you can telnet to 1.33.33.127:7612, TCP,1.33.33.127:7712  ports. These are thrift ports openning at BAM server, you can see BAM starting logs have this ports details.

Comment: The port 7712 is listening.
But the telnet won't connect
I have upload a image from the console

Comment: OK this means, you have some problem with routing better you solve it,  but if you like to use localhost instead of IP, please define hostname as "localhost"  in thriftDataReceiver  section in file <BAM>repository/conf/data-bridge/data-bridge-config.xml file, and restart servers.

Comment: I have opened the file and the tag <hostName> it's commented.
<!-- Default configuration for thriftDataReceiver -->
    <thriftDataReceiver>
    <!--<hostName>localhost</hostName>-->
        <port>7611</port>
        <securePort>7711</securePort>
    </thriftDataReceiver>

Comment: Fine, so un-comment hostname to take localhost and verify as I had requested on last comment.